# Как предотвратить ввод значений ниже нуля?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, я новичек в этой сфере и поэтому все еще учусь простым вещам.

Делаю программу, чтобы хранила сведения о продуктах в одном каталоге, но я не хочу чтобы можно было поставить негативную цену на продукт или сделать негативное кол-во продуктов на складе.

**Вот мой код:**

```
public enum ProductCategory
{
    Electric,
    Household,
    Garden,
    Miscellaneous
}
class Product
{
    // Properties
    private int productID;
    private string productName;
    private double unitPrice;
    private double unitsInStock;

    // Get Product Categories
    public ProductCategory category
    {
        get;
    }

    // Validator for Unit Price
    public double UnitPrice
    {
        get { return unitPrice; }
        set { unitPrice = value > 0.0 ? value : 0.0; }
    }

    // Validator for Units In Stock
    public double UnitsInStock
    {
        get { return unitsInStock; }
        set { unitsInStock = value > 0.0 ? value : 0.0; }
    }

    // Constructor
    public Product(int productID, string productName, ProductCategory category, double unitPrice, double unitsInStock)
    {
        this.productID = productID;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.category = category;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

    // Default Constructor with Chaining
    public Product(int productID, string productName) : this(productID, productName, ProductCategory.Miscellaneous, 0.0, 0.0)
    {
    }

    // Override which returns a string with full product information
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "The product " + productName + " with ID " + productID +
            " costs " + unitPrice + " euro per unit. We have " + unitsInStock + " items left in our " + category + " stock.";
    }
}

//Testing the app
class TestProduct
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Assigning correct properties to the product
        Product p1 = new Product(1234567, "Cake", ProductCategory.Miscellaneous, 7.5, 150);
        Product p2 = new Product(2345678, "Drill", ProductCategory.Household, -23, 2);
        Product p3 = new Product(3456789, "Shovel", ProductCategory.Garden, 12.7, -10);

        Console.WriteLine(p1);
        Console.WriteLine(p2);
        Console.WriteLine(p3);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Вот что выдает консоль:**

```
The product Cake with ID 1234567 costs 7.5 euro per unit. We have 150 items left in our Miscellaneous stock.
The product Drill with ID 2345678 costs -23 euro per unit. We have 2 items left in our Household stock.
The product Shovel with ID 3456789 costs 12.7 euro per unit. We have -10 items left in our Garden stock.
```

Как вы видите у меня цена на Drill -23 евро, а количество Shovel на складе -10.

Как сделать так, чтобы при негативных цифрах возращало 0?

Comment: При вводе отрицательных значений надо это проверять и выдавать ошибку пользователю, а не тихо изменять на ноль или брать модуль.

Comment: Поддерживаю, тихушечное глотание ошибок чревато жирными проблемами. Неправильное значение должно приводить к исключению.

Comment: @teran поделитесь пожалуйста как выдавать ошибку, а не изменять на 0.

Comment: @VladD тут скорее проблемы с проектированием. По идее эти проверки должны быть избыточны. Но это же учебный проект.

Comment: @VladD поделитесь пожалуйста как улучшить этот код.

Comment: @Rufat: Например, как-то так: `set { if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentException("UnitPrice must be positive!"); unitPrice = value; }`

Comment: @Trymount учиться лучше сразу правильно. И в данном случае, контроль диапазона значений не является избыточным даже для учебного проекта. ИМХО, проверка на ввод "не числа" для учебного проекта избыточна, и то зависит от того чему учит проект.

Comment: @rdorn Я имел ввиду, что по идее вы не должны создавать объект на основе неправильных данных. Сначала проверить валидность, потом создавать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас уже вроде всё сделано. Просто в конструкторе присваивайте значения не полям метода, а свойствам:

```
//this.unitPrice= unitPrice; 
this.UnitPrice= unitPrice;`
```

Comment: Спасибо, упустил. Все работает.

Answer (score 5):

Вставлю свои пять копеек. Для правильной обработки ошибок ввода со стороны пользователя программы в .Net существует [**IDataErrorInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) и более новый вариант на эту же тему [**INotifyDataErrorInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), очень рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией про эти интерфейсы.

Comment: когда направляете читать документацию, оставляйте ссылки для быстрого перехода

Comment: @rdorn OK, учту.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к существующих хорошим ответам: молчаливое подавление проблемы — не самая хорошая идея, т. к. при этом ошибки в других частях программы остаются незамеченными.

Есть два подхода. Во-первых, это проверки времени компиляции. Допустим, что у вас целочисленное поле, и вы хотите, чтобы оно принимало лишь положительные значения. Тогда часто имеет смысл объявить его не как `int`, а как `uint` (хотя при этом нарушится CLS compilance), чтобы отрицательные значения просто не смогли попасть туда.

В случае, если проверка во время компиляции невозможна или непрактична (например, у вас есть требования к CLS compliancy, или как в вашем случае несущий тип с плавающей запятой, который невозможно ограничить на этапе компиляции), имеет смысл бросать исключение при неверных параметрах. Таким образом, любой код, который пытается загрузить неправильные значения, приведёт к исключению и падению программы на этапе тестирования.

При этом ваш код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public double UnitPrice
{
    get { return unitPrice; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0.0) // или <= в зависимости от того, какая логика вам нужна
            throw new ArgumentException("Unit price cannot be negative");
        unitPrice = value;
    }
}
```